# Linux grep y egrip

Tags: linux, grep

I am just starting with Linux and I had a question that I could not answer, it goes. Using grep or egrip how can I catch Mr. or Mrs., but not Mra from my DisneyCharacters file. My answer was : egrep "(Mr.|Mrs.)" DisneyCharacters but it still gives me the Mra

Comment: See [this cross-site duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258860/how-do-i-grep-the-lines-based-on-dot). The problem is that `.` means "any character", so you have to either use `\.` or `[.]` if you want an actual dot

Comment: I have used a different one and it worked out, thanks for your answer:  grep Mr.[^a] DisneyCharacters

Comment: Please be aware that `Mr.[^a]` will match `Mrax` while `Mr[^a]` will match `Mrb`